# Can you define a type for a function as an argument in python using mypy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mypy

I'm trying to annotate and define my types in python 2.7 using mypy.  I can't seem to find any documentation describing how one might pass a function as an argument and record its type.  For example, in Scala I can define a function type which maps two ints to a boolean as:

```
def exampleFunction(f: (Int,Int) => Boolean) = {
  // Do Something
}
```

Is there similar notation in mypy? Something like this perhaps?

```
def exampleFunction(f):
    # type: ((int, int) -> bool) -> None
    # Do Something
```

What is the best practice for annotating function types when they are arguments?

Comment: In Python 3, you'd use [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable). I'm not sure how that interacts with the Python 2 type comment notation, but I think there's a `typing` backport for Python 2.

Comment: Thanks!  Callable was what I was looking for.  In python 2.7 you can do this # type: Callable[[int, int], bool].  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

You could write your function as

```
def exampleFunction(f: Callable[[int, int], bool]):
    # Do Something
```

#### More cases:

In principle, the syntax is `Callable[[<parameters>], <return type>]`

Some examples, for the 3 possible types of functions

1. function `f` with parameters and return
2. function `g` with only return
3. function `h` with only parameters

I made 3 check-functions, that take the function as input. I want to illustrate what type to give to a parameter if this parameter is a function.

```py
from typing import Callable


    def f(i: int) -> bool:
        return i > 0

    def g() -> bool:
        return True

    def h(i: int, j: int):
        pass

    def check_f(function: Callable[[int], bool]):
        print(function(1))

    def check_g(function: Callable[[], bool]):
        print(function())

    def check_h(function: Callable[[int, int], None]):
        print(function(1, 1))

    check_f(f)
    check_g(g)
    check_h(h)
```

prints

```
True
True
None
```

Mypy says: `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`